# Castle Windsor registration using FromAssembly requires some 3rd party referenced dlls but not all

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a separate project that I use to handle all of my Castle Windsor setup and installers.

In one installer I am trying to register repositories by conventions using:

```
Classes.FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(BaseRepository)).BasedOn(typeof(IRepository))
.WithServiceSelf()
```

When I use any form of FromAssembly in any installer in the project I will get an exception when the installer is executed that it cannot locate a certain 3rd party dll.

However if I register the components individually:

```
Component.For<IVendorRepository>().ImplementedBy<VendorRepository>()
Component.For<IContactRepository>().ImplementedBy<ContactRepository>()
```

I do not get the error and the configured container is returned as expected.

The especially frustrating thing is that not all of my 3rd party dlls are required in the bin folder when using FromAssembly, only a select few.

What is happening when using FromAssembly that causes certain dlls to be required and others left as optional?

Is there a way to register by convention without having to use FromAssembly?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information here to definitely state WHY some 3rd party assemblies are being required and others aren't.  My best guess is because some of the 3rd party libraries are currently loaded when you begin registering components via convention whereas others aren't.

However, to answer your question, yes, you can register by convention while avoiding specific assemblies.  One option around this (in [Castle Windsor 3.x](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md)) is to register only components in your application's root namespace, preventing 3rd party dlls from getting registered.

```
 Classes
    .FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(BaseRepository))
    .BasedOn(typeof(IRepository))
    .WithServiceSelf()
    .Where(Component.IsInNamespace("Your.Application.Namespace"))
```